# Google Search Console detects issue with noindex pages excluded from sitemap, why? How to resolve?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, sitemap, noindex

Google emails me this:

> Message type: [WNC-10030322]
>
> **Search Console**
>
> **Page indexing issues detected in [DOMAIN]**
>
> To the owner of [DOMAIN]:
>
> Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site.
>
> **Top Issues**
>
> - Excluded by ‘noindex’ tag
>
> We recommend that you fix these issues when
> possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.
>
> **Fix Page indexing issues**

I don’t want the page indexed. It is not listed in my `/sitemap.txt` file. Why am I getting this issue? Is it harmful to my SEO? Thank you.

Comment: The noindex tag prevents search engines from indexing the page, which means that the page won't appear in search results. However, if you are sure that the page should not be indexed, you are free to ignore it. Having a page excluded by a noindex tag generally won't harm your SEO.

As for why you received the message, it's possible that the page was previously indexed before you added the noindex tag. Even though you removed the page from your sitemap, it may still be in Google's index.

Comment: I believe you can ignore this. Google tends to present things as an "issue" when it doesn't get everything it wants - i.e. full reign over your site. Google should really call it a "notification" instead of an "issue", because it's fine and expected if you're trying to prevent some of your pages from being indexed.